# How to organise absolute paths in git repo?

Tags: git, git-config

I have git repository, where R and python scripts are located. And every script need to change a workdir. Something like this:

```
os.chdir("~/reponame/folder1/")
```

Also users will clone it not only to home folder. So how i can make the first part of a path - flexible?

Comment: I feel like you’re missing a tag here. What is the context of this question?

Comment: What is that "the first part"? Do you want to `chdir` to the repository, where the scripts reside? `os.chdir(path_to_the script)`?

Comment: phd, "first part" - is the all before "reponame"(~ in exmpl).

Comment: Require all users to define an env-variable pointing to the owning folder of the cloned git repos, and use the env-variable along with the relative path in your scripts..

Answer (score 0):

From anywhere inside the repo you can get the `~/reponame` prefix by running `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.

From outside, you'll have to use convention, an environment var or a home-based conventional pathname or some such.  Perhaps the easiest for users to set up would be a git config entry, they do

```
git config --global my.reporoot.path ~
```

and you do

```
MY_REPOROOT=`git config my.reporoot.path`
MY_REPOROOT=${MY_REPOROOT:-$HOME}  # default
```